# Using variables as command arguments in zsh

Tags: variables, zsh, variable-expansion, fzf

I'm trying to write a function for zsh to find files with fzf and directly open them in my editor.
The arguments for the call to fzf are stored in a variable like so:

```
FZF_FILE_PREVIEW="--preview 'cat {}) 2> /dev/null | head -200'"
```

the function looks like this:

```
fzf_find_edit() {
    local file=$(fzf ${FZF_FILE_PREVIEW})
    if [[ -n $file ]]; then
        $EDITOR $file
    fi
}
```

But it seems `FZF_FILE_PREVIEW` doesn't get expanded correctly, because, when I run the function, I get:

```
unknown option: --preview 'cat {}) 2> /dev/null | head -200'
```

If I directly run

```
fzf --preview 'cat {}) 2> /dev/null | head -200'
```

it works as expected.

How do I get the varible to expand properly?

Comment: Do you _have_ to put the pipe into your variable? If you had no pipe, `${(z)FZF_FILE_PREVIEW}` would do the job, but the input line is partitioned into individual commands before the substitution applies, and the shell doesn't see your pipe. The only alternative I am aware of, would be to use `eval`, but of course this is awful.

Comment: Ah, I just see that the pipe is part of the --preview option! In this case, the trick with the `(z)` expansion flag should work. Let me know if it does.

Comment: The expression got more complex. So the (z) flag doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the zsh IRC channel, I figured hew to solve this:

The variable gets assigned an array, using ():

```
FZF_FILE_PREVIEW=(--preview 'cat {}) 2> /dev/null | head -200')
```

and then can be referenced as:

```
file=($(fzf ${FZF_FILE_PREVIEW}))
```

only when exporting the array it gets tricky:

```
export FZF_CTRL_T_OPTS=${(j< >)${(@q-)FZF_FILE_PREVIEW}}
```

joins the elements of the array, further explanation in the [docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion).