# Make ZSH pass a variable as space-delimited parameters

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sh, zsh

I would like to create an alias that works in zsh and bash, but weirdly enough zsh tries to pass on an unquoted variable as a single argument:

```bash
❯ zsh -f
grasshopper% LS_OPTIONS="-l -a" && ls $LS_OPTIONS
ls: invalid option -- ' '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
grasshopper% bash --norc
bash-5.1$ LS_OPTIONS="-l -a" && ls $LS_OPTIONS
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 janekf janekf   40 28. Nov 14:02 .
drwxrwxrwt 24 root   root   2400 28. Nov 16:41 ..
```

Is there a option to stop that?

See also [Using variables as command arguments in zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051116/using-variables-as-command-arguments-in-zsh), but the answer there is zsh-specific.

Comment: I don't see any `alias` definition in the question you asked, so it's hard to discuss your problem. Also, I don''t consider it very sensible for code which works the same in bash and zsh. What's the point for it? You wouldn't ask either for a program which works the same in Python or Perl, don't you? They are different languages and you better try to find a solution for the respective language individually.

Comment: I always prefer zsh, but from time to time I encounter a situation where I am stuck with bash but would still like to use my dotfiles. This works pretty good now.

Comment: The alias is `alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something that works in both `zsh` and `bash`, use an array.

```
LS_OPTIONS=(-l -a) && ls "${LS_OPTIONS[@]}"
```

You can set the `SH_WORD_SPLIT` option in `zsh` to make parameter expansions undergo word-splitting just as in `bash`, but unquoted expansions in `bash` are subject to pathname expansion as well, so I don't recommend their use.

Comment: since I use this in an environment variable controlled by myself, that option is the perfect solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your LS_OPTIONS will be passed as a single parameter to `ls`, and of course `ls` can not handle it.

In zsh, define your alias as

```
 alias ls='ls ${(z)LS_OPTIONS}'
```

The *(z)* causes the value to be split on white space and passed as individual arguments to `ls`.

Comment: which won't work in bash, right?

Comment: @xeruf : Of course not. For bash, you use bash-Syntax, and for zsh, you use zsh-Syntax. There is nearly never a need to write a command which works the same under both shells, and the alias definitions would typically end up in the specific configuration file for the respective shell.